# How to add songs queued by the music lens to "now playing" in banshee?

Tags: 11.10, unity, banshee

When you add a song from the Unity music lens, it gets added to the "file system queue" in banshee. The problem is that, the file system queue being its own "playlist", when the song is finished banshee will continue playing only the songs in the file system queue i.e. only the songs I've added through the lens or nautilus.

Is there anyway to make banshee, once it completes the song specified in the music lens, return to its original playlist/playback? I usually just play directly off of my entire music library (not in playlists), so I guess that it doesn't have to resume playback of a specific playlist, just of the entire library.

One way to solve this could be by adding the enire library to the filesystem queue, but this is obviously impractical (and must be done manually). Another way would be to add all my library to the "play queue" (or a new playlist) and then make banshee play songs added through the lens within the play queue/playlist (if resuming to library is not possible). Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question was closed as 'not likely useful'. But I would have found an answer to this very useful. Same problem here.